# Multiple values IN

Tags: sql, postgresql, in-subquery

Normally IN is used with one value:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE f1 IN (<subquery>)
```

It is possible to use it with multiple values:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE f1 IN (<subquery>) OR f2 IN (<subquery>);
```

But can I remove duplication, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE ANY(f1, f1) IN (<subquery>)
```

I tried to use CTE, but it also require subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While both solutions works, I have found that fastest (unfortunately not shortest) way is to use CTE:

```
WITH x AS (<subquery>)
SELECT * FROM data WHERE f1 IN (SELECT * FROM x) OR f2 (SELECT * FROM x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have columns `col1`,`col2`, and `col3` and that you're looking for `col1` and `col2` in your subquery (for the sake of illustration), you can do something like:

```
select col1,col2,col3
from table
where (col1,col2) in (<subquery>)
group by 1,2,3;
```

As long as `<subquery>` is of the (rough) form `select col1,col2 from <blah>`, then you'll end up with distinct `(col1,col2,col3)` triples where `(col1,col2)` pairs appear in `<subquery>`.

Answer (score 1):

I might write this in terms of set operators:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE EXISTS (
    VALUES(f1, f2)

    INTERSECT

    SELECT(<subquery>)
)
```